# Making a line in a matrix go up (Python) - issue with Append that replace instead of Appending item

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I want to make an "animation" of an element of matrix going from the bottom line to the top ligne of the matrix.
I have the following code, but something not wanted is ongoing with append function :

```
import time
#size of the matrix
PixelCarac=4
#List that cointain all the matrixs
ListMatrix=[]
#matrix  filled with 0
tempo =[[0 for x in range(PixelCarac)] for y in range(PixelCarac)] 
#last line have a difference
tempo[3][0]=1
print("First step")
print(tempo)    

#making the line going up.  
for x in range(0,PixelCarac-1,1):   
    #append in the list
    ListMatrix.append(tempo)
    #display 
    print("length of the list is " + str(len(ListMatrix)))
    for elem in ListMatrix:
        print(elem)     

    #Making the line going up by recopie from 1 line to the upper one
    for i in range(0,len(tempo)-1,1):   
        tempo[i]=tempo[i+1]                     

time.sleep(20)
```

**the ouput I have is :**

First step

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]

length of the list is 1

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]

length of the list is 2

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,**1**],[0,0,0,1]

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1]

length of the list is 2

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,**1**],[0,0,0,**1**],[0,0,0,1]

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,**1**],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1]

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1]

**the ouput I want is  :**

First step

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]

length of the list is 1

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]

length of the list is 2

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[**0**,0,0,1]

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1]

length of the list is 2

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,**0**],[0,0,0,**0**],[0,0,0,1]

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,**0**],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1]

[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1]

**Question :**

Why the *append* function is changing the previous items in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what you want, this might be a direction:

```
import time
#size of the matrix
PixelCarac=4
#List that cointain all the matrixs
ListMatrix=[]
#matrix  filled with 0
tempo =[[0 for x in range(PixelCarac)] for y in range(PixelCarac)]
#last line have a difference
tempo[3][3]=1
print("First step")
print(tempo)

#making the line going up.  
for x in range(0,PixelCarac-1,1):
    #append in the list
    ListMatrix.append(tempo)
    #display 
    print("length of the list is " + str(len(ListMatrix)))
    for elem in ListMatrix:
        print(elem)

    #Making the line going up by recopie from 1 line to the upper one
    #for i in range(0,len(tempo)-1,1):   
    #    tempo[i]=tempo[i+1]                     
    tempo = tempo[1:]+[tempo[3]]

time.sleep(20)
```

Gives:

```
First step
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
length of the list is 1
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
length of the list is 2
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
length of the list is 3
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```